# What is the variance of a Brownian Bridge with vertical "gaps"?

Tags: variance, prediction, brownian-motion

Suppose I have a simple Brownian bridge with $B(0)=0$ and $B(1)=0$.

Further I know for some $t \in (0,1)$ and $y>0$ that $B(t) \notin (-y,y)$.

As far as I understand, the expected value on the entire $[0,1]$ remains $0$, but I am confused how to calculate the variance on $(0,t)$ and $(t,1)$. Is there a simple way?

Second, and related: Suppose I want to define a prediction interval for some $x \in [0,1]$ given the above knowledge (say I want the interval $[\underline{y},\overline{y}]\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $B(x)$ is in that interval with 95%).

How would the prediction interval look like?

Comment: Your quantification "for some" is ambiguous: surely you mean that you have *specified* such a $y,$ right?  Otherwise, it is almost surely the case that "for some $y$" (that is, *there exists* a $y$) for which $B(t)\notin (-y,y).$